# ios 8 doesn't pop the permission for notification when installing the app

Tags: ios8, push-notification

On lower versions of IOS everything works fine, my code for push notifications:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
        {
                UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
                [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        }
        else
        {
            UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
            [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
        }
        application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
{
    //register to receive notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

//for sielent notifications
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler
{
}
#endif

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
{
    NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
}
```

1) when running for the first time push notification popup asking for permission is not being called even when i re-call it using [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications]; the popup is not showing.

Comment: have you created and assigned new provisioning profile after creating APNS certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Push Notifications are configured for your [App ID](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action).
If not, the device will ignore any push related methods.
[image]